# Importance of Log Convexity of the Gamma Function

Tags: gamma-function

The Bohr-Mollerup theorem states that the Gamma function is the unique function that satisfies:

1) f(x+1) = x*f(x)

2) f(1) = 1

3) ln(f(x)) is convex

The Gamma function is meant to interpolate the factorial function, so I can see the importance of the first two properties. But why is log convexity important? How does it affect the Gamma function's applicability in other areas of mathematics?

Comment: There is also Weilandt's characterisation of the gamma function, it is the unique meromorphic function which is bounded in vertical strips.

Comment: From 1) (for natural x only) and 2) you can prove that ln(f(x)) is convex on the natural numbers.  This doesn't explain why 3) is "important", but does explain why it's a natural property to ask for general x, and it's interesting that only one extension of the factorial keeps this property.

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/why-is-eulers-gamma-function-the-best-extension-of-the-factorial-function-to

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, let me mention that log convexity of a function is implied by an analytic property, which appears to be more natural than log convexity itself. Namely, if $\mu$ is a  Borel measure on $[0,\infty)$ such that the $r$th moment 
$$f(r)=\int_{0}^{\infty}z^r d\mu(z)$$
is finite for all $r$ in the interval $I\subset \mathbb R$, then $\log f$ is convex on $I$.

Log convexity can be effectively used in derivation of various inequalities involving the gamma function (particularly, two-sided estimates of products of gamma functions).  It is linked with the notion of [Schur convexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) which is itself used in many applications.

**An appetizer.** Let $m=\max x_i$, $s=\sum x_i$, $x_i > 0$, $i = 1,\dots,n$, then
$$[\Gamma(s/n)]^n\leq\prod\limits_{1}^{n}\Gamma (x_i)\leq \left[\Gamma\left(\frac{s-m}{n-1}\right)\right]^{n-1}\Gamma(m).\qquad\qquad\qquad  (1)$$

(1) is trivial, of course, when all $x_i$ and $s/n$ are integers, but in general the bounds do not hold without assuming log convexity.

**Edit added: a sketch of the proof**. Let $f$ be a continuous positive function defined on an interval $I\subset \mathbb R$. One may show that the function $\phi(x)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i)$, $x\in I^n$ is Schur-convex on $I^n$ if and only if $\log f$ is convex on $I$. Thus the function 
$$\phi(x)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \Gamma(x_i),\quad x_i>0,\qquad \quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad   (2)$$ 
is Schur-convex on $I^n=(0,\infty)^n$. Since $x_i\le m$, $i=1,\dots,n$, and $\sum x_i=s$, it is easy to check that 
$$x \prec \left(\frac{s-m}{n-1},\dots,\frac{s-m}{n-1},m\right).$$
The latter [majorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) and the fact that $\phi(x)$ defined by (2) is Schur-convex imply the upper bound (1). The lower bound follows from the standard majorization $x\succ (s/n,\dots,s/n)$.

---

Have a look at [the recent short article](http://www.springerlink.com/content/k4285g1811744605/) by  Marshall and Olkin concerning this and related inequalities for the gamma function.

Comment: What is the finite Borel measure? Specifically, since $\Gamma(0)=\infty,$ doesn't this imply that $\mu$ is infinite?

Comment: Thanks, Victor. I amended the statement to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: The link for the Marshall-Olkin article is no longer available, but I suppose the intended paper is this: https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-7643-8773-0_23

Answer (score 12):

There is a lovely and detailed discussion of the uniqueness of the gamma function in Volume 2 of Markushevich's Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable. The essential points are
as follows.

Any meromorphic solution $f$ to the functional equation $zf(z)=f(z+1)$, with $f(1)=1$, must have simple poles at all integers $m\le 0$ with residues $(-1)^m/m!$  Assuming that these are ALL the poles of $f$, Markushevich exhibits all meromorphic interpolations of the factorial  function. It turns out that there is a whole zoo of them, and in some (not very satisfying)  sense the usual gamma function is the simplest choice.

So ... The Bohr-Mollerup Theorem sheds some light on this situation. But maybe there are other "interesting" extensions of the factorial  that are not log-convex.