# Holomorphic vector fields and derivations

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $M$ be a complex manifold and $U\subset M$ a domain.

**Question:** Is every derivation of the complex algebra of holomorphic functions $\mathcal{O}(U)$ induced by a holomorphic vector field defined on $U$?

I think this is true if $M$ is Stein, by a similar proof to the smooth case (using Cartan B instead of bump functions), but I cannot see if it holds in the general case.

Comment: As  a  related post please see the 
 following real version https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158776/derivation-on-real-analytic-manifolds