# Derivations of $\chi^{\infty}(M)$ which are elliptic operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, differential-operators

What is  an  example  of  a manifold $M$ with $\dim(M)>1$ whose Lie  algebra $\chi^{\infty}(M)$  of  smooth vector  fields admit an elliptic operator $D:\chi^{\infty}(M)\to \chi^{\infty}(M)$   such that $D$ is  a  Lie  algebra  derivation on $\chi^{\infty}(M)$?

Does every  manifold admit such an  operator?

Is there  a  Riemannian  manifold for  which the  Laplace operator $D=\Delta$,   naturally defined on $\chi^{\infty}(M)\simeq \Omega^1(M)$,  would  be  a  derivation  of $\chi^{\infty}(M)$?

Answer (score 2):

First a classical result about elliptic operators: in dimension $\ge 3$ the order of elliptic operators is even. In dimension 2, say in $\mathbb R^2$ you have elliptic vector fields such as
$$
\bar \partial=\frac12(\partial_x+i\partial_y),\quad \partial=\frac12(\partial_x-i\partial_y).
$$
Of course vector fields are derivations and I suspect that, since a derivation on a manifold must be a differential operator, that differential operator must be first-order from Leibniz' formula and thus should be a vector field since no mutiplication by a (non-zero) function is a derivation.

Comment: Thanks  for  your  answer. Is there a  complete  classification of  all derivations  of $\chi^{\infty}(M)$?(as  a  vector  field  analogy  of the  fact that every derivation of  $C^{\infty}(M)$, the  space of  smooth functions on $M$ is in the  form $f\mapsto  X.f$ for  a  unique  vector  field on $M$? what is  your argument  that every derivation on the  space of  vector fields is of first order?What is  your  argument that 
 every  elliptic  operator  on the  sections  of  a  vector  bundle  of rank greater than 1 is off even degree?

Comment: Finally is not the  operator  $(u,v,w)\mapsto  (u_x-v_y,u_y+v_x,w)$ counted  as an elliptic operator?

Comment: Do not  you think that the  classical result you  mentioned is  about  "functions" not  vector  fields?what is  a  proof  of that classical result(or  a  reference, please)?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to apply the hints presented in the answer by Bazin to give the following answer.

[Every derivation of $\chi^{\infty}(M)$ is inner](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1981__43_2_239_0.pdf) and it is obvious that  every inner derivation is a non elliptic operator. The reason is that every non vanishing vector field is locally look like $\partial/\partial_x$, whose corresponding adjoint operator is obviousely non elliptic.

So the non ellipticity of a derivation operator lies in its adjoint-ness not merely on its order.It is first order but this order situation is not enough to conclude it is non elliptic. In fact there is an example of a first order elliptic pde in dim 3 as follows:
$$D(u,v, w)= (u_x-v_y, u_y+v_x, w)$$

This operator  $D$ satisfies the definition of an elliptic PDE but is of first order.

One can construct a first order elliptic PDE in dimension 4 without a term of order 0. Construct a linear PDE on $\chi^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^4)$ whose principal symbol is the $4\times 4$ matrix representation of quaterniouns $$\xi_1+\xi_2 i + \xi_3 j+\xi_4 k$$ where $(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4)$ is a cotangent vector.

So it seems that the first line of the answer by Bazin does not work.

**Remark:**  The above linked paper contains a reference to a result by F.Takens that every derivation of $\chi^{\infty}(M)$ is an inner derivation.