# An interpolation of $n!$ such that its derivatives have few zeros

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function

The $\Gamma$-function restricted to $(0,+\infty)$ has the following properties:

1. $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ for $n=1,2,3,...$.
2. The $k$'th derivative $\Gamma^{(k)}$ has no zeros on $(0,+\infty)$ when $k$ is even (starting from $k=0$), and it has exactly one zero when $k$ is odd.

I wonder whether there exists another real analytic (or at least $C^\infty$) function $(0,+\infty)\to\mathbb R$ enjoying these properties.
If there are many, I'd like a description of the union of their plots in $(0,+\infty)\times\mathbb R$.

Comment: Is it possible given the uniqueness of the Gamma function? (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23229/importance-of-log-convexity-of-the-gamma-function)

Comment: Not if the properties 1 and 2 imply the hypothesis of the uniqueness theorem, i. e., log-convexity and the functional equation. But how can we prove that?